# Drag & Drop from email to desktop not landing at designated spot. Finder opening when dragging to desktop

Tags: finder, desktop, icon, ui

When I drag an item (i.e. a jpeg) from my email to the desktop, the icon for said item appears all the way to the right of the screen as opposed to where it dropped it on the desktop. This only started happening recently. Also, When I drag the photo to the desktop a finder folder now opens whereas this didnt used to happen. any ideas would be greatly appreciated! thanks!

Comment: I've answered for the first part. But it's not clear as to what Finder window opens when you drag a photo to the desktop. Please edit your question and provide more details (like where you drop it, which folder opens, etc., if necessary, with a screenshot).

Answer (score 1):

Your "Show View Options" may have been changed recently to sort items by name or date or size or kind or label.

- Click anywhere on the desktop (except on any file/folder)
- Press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> (or use the mouse to go to the Finder's **View > Show View Options** menu)
- In the **Sort by:** dropdown in the dialog, choose either **None** or **Snap to Grid**
- Now you'll be able to drop files at specific locations on the desktop